# Visual Studio Code crashes with 'out of memory' error

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, out-of-memory

I have a php script which fetches product data from a website and inserts it into my database. The script runs the operations for about 15.000 products. Even though getting the website data for every product takes some time the code worked perfectly fine yesterday. Today it started to make some troubles. Everytime I run the script after about 150 products Visual Studio Code crashes with the following message:(reason: oom, code: -536870904).

Here is a screenshot:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNoRH.png

My VS Code version is: 1.67.1

My PHP version is: 8.1.2

I hope a little pseudo-code helps to understand the problem a little bit better, so here it is:

```
    try
    {
        // Fetching Product Ids from xml file

        $start=hrtime(true);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($productIdList);$i++)
        {
            // Fetching information about the product from a website using cUrl request

            for($j = 0; $j < count($storedItemIds); $j++)
            {
                // Check if Items is already stored 
                // If is stored, check if something has changed and update it.
            }
            
            // If item does not exist in database, insert it.
        }
        
        $conn->commit();

        $end=hrtime(true);
        $eta=$end-$start;
        echo $eta/1e+6;
    }
    catch(Exception $minifigEx)
    {
        $conn->rollback();
        // Logging error
    }
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: What do you mean, after 150 products? Show us the code where it happens, then we might be able to help.

Comment: Updated the question and added some schematic example of my code. 150 products mean, that it crashes after looping throught the ProductIdList for about 150 times.

Comment: This appears to be "normal": https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+536870904